# Android Animation one after other

Tags: android, animation

I have two TranslateAnimations on a TextView and I want them to execute one after other. However, by using the code below, only the second one is executed.

How can I solve this?

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -150.0f);
animation.setDuration(200);
wave.startAnimation(animation);

TranslateAnimation animation1 = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 150.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);
animation1.setDuration(200);
wave.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Comment: Have you tried [AnimationSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html)?

Comment: not working properly update this

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**EDIT:** Andy Boots answer below is the better answer imo.

---

Just set your first one like this and it'll start the other one, once the animation finishes:

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            wave.startAnimation(animation1);

        }
    });
```

edit: The reason only your second animation is executed with your current code, is because it overrides the playing of the first animation (both actually are played, but you only see the latest one to start). If you do like I wrote, they will play sequentially instead of in parallel.

Comment: Thanks
Try'd it and it works as i wanted... but just curious, is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: Thanks. It Works how i m searching for. . .

Comment: "just set ur flirst one leik dis n' it'll start teh" - Damn... Go to school. :)

Comment: Would you be able to assist with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899280/multiple-xml-animation-is-not-working @pgsandstrom

Answer (score 61):

Link them together with 
[Animation Set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html)

```
AnimationSet as = new AnimationSet(true)
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -150.0f);
animation.setDuration(200);
as.addAnimation(animation);

TranslateAnimation animation1 = new TranslateAnimation(
Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
Animation.ABSOLUTE, 150.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);
animation1.setDuration(200);
animation1.setStartOffset(200);
as.addAnimation(animation1);

wave.startAnimation(as);
```

Comment: This is wonderful. However this seems to serialize animations only for one object. If you have to serialize animations for different objects, you will have to use different approaches.

Comment: this worked for me, but in the wrong order, the animation I put first came second, how to solve?

Answer (score 12):

also you can do this by XML itself using `android:startOffset` attribute , and there is an examble:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="0%"
        android:fromYScale="0%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha=".5" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha=".5"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 8):

There is one more approach to reach this goal which can be useful when you need to animate a lot of views one after another. You can use `setStartOffset` method to set a delay before animation begins. So, if you know, how much time will take for your first animation to end, you can set this as a delay for your second animation. This is an example where I animated six `ImageButtons` and six `TextViews` below them one after another:

```
public void animateButtons() {
    // An array of buttons
    int[] imageButtonIds = {R.id.searchButton, R.id.favoriteButton, R.id.responseButton, R.id.articleButton, R.id.resumeButton, R.id.subscribeButton};
    // Array of textViews
    int[] textViewIds = {R.id.searchTextView, R.id.favoriteTextView, R.id.responseTextView, R.id.articleTextView, R.id.resumeTextView, R.id.subscribeTextView};

    int i = 1;

    for (int viewId : imageButtonIds) {

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(viewId);
        // Animation from a file fade.xml in folder res/anim
        Animation fadeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
        // Delay for each animation is 100 ms bigger than for previous one
        fadeAnimation.setStartOffset(i * 100);
        imageButton.startAnimation(fadeAnimation);

        // The same animation is for textViews
        int textViewId = textViewIds[i-1];
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
        textView.startAnimation(fadeAnimation);

        i ++;
    }
}
```

In my `res/anim` folder I have a file, called `fade.xml` with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--  Fade animation with 500 ms duration -->

<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:duration="500" />
```

Comment: not worked for me |-) fadeAnimation.setStartOffset changes root animation. is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Create an animation array and use method for creating AnimationSet.

```
    Animation[] animations = { 
            getScaleAnimation(0.4f, 1.3f, 2000), 
            getScaleAnimation(1.3f, 1.0f, 500), 
            getScaleAnimation(0.4f, 1.3f, 1000),
            getScaleAnimation(1.3f, 1.0f, 3000), 
            getScaleAnimation(0.4f, 1.3f, 500), 
            getScaleAnimation(1.3f, 1.0f, 1700), 
            getScaleAnimation(0.4f, 1.3f, 2100),
            getScaleAnimation(1.3f, 1.0f, 3400)  
    };
    AnimationSet animationSet = addAnimationAr(animations);
    view.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

Method:

```
public static AnimationSet addAnimationAr(Animation[] animations) {
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    long totalAnimationDuration = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
        Animation a = animations[i];
        a.setStartOffset(totalAnimationDuration);
        totalAnimationDuration += a.getDuration();
        animationSet.addAnimation(a);
    }

    return animationSet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use code, you can call

```
Animation.setStartOffset()
```

to delay the second animation.

if you use xml you can `android:ordering="sequentially"` property to make the two animations perform sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

#### For simple animations, you can achieve this by using the `animate()` and `withEndAction()` functions, like so:

```
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.animate().rotation(180).alpha(0).setDuration(3000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            img.animate().rotation(0).alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great idea! I tried using `it.animate().yBy(-10F).withEndAction { it.animate().yBy(10F) }` for a "jump" and if you tap it repeatedly it shoots to the moon. I suppose I have to hard-code the `y`?

Answer (score 0):

## AnimationDrawable

Running such animation is pretty straightforward in Android. In fact, there is a class in Android API just for this specific task called [AnimationDrwable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation#java). AnimationDrawable is a set of images together.

**Step1: Create AnimationDrwable

Step2: Load Animation Drawable into ImageView

step3: start the animation**

Step 1:
Create an XML and add all images like this.

```
<animation-list 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:oneshot="true">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_image_1" android:duration="200" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_image_2" android:duration="200" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/cat_image_3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Step 2:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    //Step 2
    ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    myimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);

    //Step 3
    AnimationDrawable catAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
    catAnimation.start();

}
```