# Can I launch an Android animation in the onanimationEnd callback of the previous one?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am attempting to launch one animation after another has finished by monitoring the onanimationEnd callback of the first one. However Android gives the following error when I attempt to do this:

Error - The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments (new Animation.AnimationListener()
 {}, int)

I tried to use the answer in this post: 
---[Android Animation one after other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other)
Which I interpreted to mean that I should move everything except the start animation out of the callback, but when I do this I get the following error:

Error - Cannot refer to a non-final variable fade3 inside an inner class defined in a different method

What am I missing here???

---

******CODE FOR FIRST EXAMPLE**********

---

```
package com.smartproducts.dragracepro;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DragRaceProSplashActivity extends DragRaceProActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        //animate title fade in
        TextView programtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
        Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in);
        programtitle.startAnimation(fade1);

        //show introduction and logo for Smart Shocks
        fade1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){         
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation fade1)
            {
***************  
ERROR IS HERE> Animation fade3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in2); ***************
            ImageView sslogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);
                sslogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sslogo.startAnimation(fade3);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        });

    }
```

Comment: ok movinbg the fade3 outside the Animation Listener AND declaring it final worked, but why? What is Adroid trying to tell me??

Comment: Would be easier to understand if you format your question a little better..

Answer (score 0):

```
Animation fade3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in2);
```

`this` is referring to the animation instead of your context as your calling it inside of a listener, If you want to use this code then you need to create a global variable of your context and use that variable in place of `this`.

Comment: or just call "DragRaceProSplashActivity.this" instead of "this"