# How to animate images one after another in android

Tags: android, animation

I have three images that depicts the company logo, name and slogan. I want to animate these three images in such a way that a logo appears first, then the name and then the slogan. After these three animations, I want the screen to disappear and display a new activity. How to do this? Please help me.

Comment: There is one more approach to do this: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20121594/751641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a listener your first animation ,  and in the method : `onAnimationEnd()` , then launch your second animation of the second image , and so on 
Example :

**NOTE :** initialise your img2 and img3 visibility to `GONE`

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener{
......
@Override 
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....

ScaleAnimation a1 , a2 , a3;
//define your animations 
a1 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f,1.0f);
a2 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f,1.0f);
a3 = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f,1.0f);

// duration and behavior of ur animations
a1.setFillAfter(true);
a1.setDuration(1000);
a2.setFillAfter(true);
a2.setDuration(1000);
a3.setFillAfter(true);
a3.setDuration(1000);

a1.setAnimationListener(this);
a2.setAnimationListener(this);
a3.setAnimationListener(this);

img1.startAnimation(a1);
}

Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a){
if(a == a1 ){ 
   img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   img2.startAnimation(a2);
}

if(a == a2){
   img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   img3.startAnimation(a3);
}

if(a == a3){
   startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this , SecondActivity.class);
}
}
}
```

Comment: What would you recommend for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899280/multiple-xml-animation-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you're going to have these three images on the same screen and then displaying each image after a certain amount of time.

As long as you aren't going to do anything while the splashscreen is showing *and* the time between images is less than five seconds, you don't *have* to use another thread.

So, the easiest way would be to set an image, sleep for say a second, then show the next image. Use a boolean so you won't show the splashscreen twice incase the user presses the back button before you were able to handle a back button press.

```
if(!showedSplash)
{
    logoImageView.setImageDrawable(R.id.drawable.company_logo);
    Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for a second (1000 ms)
    nameImageView.setImageDrawable(R.id.drawable.company_name);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    sloganImageView.setImageDrawable(R.id.drawable.company_slogan);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    showedSplash = true;'
}
```

Now to change to the next activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,activity2.class);    
startActivity(i);
```

Don't forget to put the activity in the manifest!

```
<activity android:name=".activity2" android:label="@string/activity2_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, you can read about them [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

Hope this helps!