# Android: show differents image on the imageview (one after another)

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to do a kind of hangman, so when you fail a letter there is an image that change, I have that function to do it:

```
private void drawNextHangPart() {

    if (contdraw == 1) hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangdroid1);
    else if (contdraw == 2) hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangdroid2);
    else if (contdraw == 3) hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangdroid3);
    else if (contdraw == 4) hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangdroid4);
    else hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangdroid);

}
```

Those images are .jpg format, and they are at `res/drawable-hdpi`.

The problem is that when I execute the app, it run good, but when you fail and the image must change, the app stop unexpectally.

Any one know how to do something like that?

thanks

Comment: Could you try to post your LogCat log?

Comment: In case you do not know: type `adb logcat` in a shell window, or check for a logcat tab in eclipse. This gives you the exception and on what line of your code it was thrown.

Comment: please post your log cat

Comment: check below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314975/how-to-animate-images-one-after-another-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do the change of image on the UI-thread. If you use an AsyncTask this would be in either `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate` - you can't do it in `doInBackground`.

Comment: Can you explain me how to used it? I never used threads in java.