# Animation on alternate touch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

I have two translate animation classes for the same view and what i want now is i need the view to get hide/display using alternative touches. When putting together only one animation is working and i need both to work on alternate touches. Here is my code.

```
ln.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) 
            {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,-200,0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(2000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    lv.startAnimation(animation);
                    lv.setVisibility(0);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                     Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-200,0,0, 0);
                        animation.setDuration(3000);
                        animation.setFillAfter(true);
                        lv.startAnimation(animation);
                      lv.setVisibility(0);

                }


                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other) but i still am facing the problem. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: What are you calling "alternate touch" ?  Which one of the animation is working  and what is the behavior of the "not working" animation ?

Comment: 2nd animation property is working and in first one view will get visible and in second view will get hide.alternate touch means first time when i touch view will display and next time it will get hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution to my problem. Here is the code.

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
 {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) 
     {
         if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
         {
            if(gone)
            {
                 Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-300,0,0, 0);
                 animation.setFillAfter(true);
                 animation.setDuration(500);
                 lv.setAnimation(animation);

                 gone = false;

            }
            else
            {
                 Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,-300,0, 0);
              animation.setFillAfter(true);
              animation.setDuration(500);
                 lv.setAnimation(animation);
                 gone = true;
            }
         }
        return true;
     }
 });
```

and  boolean gone = false; at the top..
Hope this will help some one :-)