# Animate Views one after another

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to animate a few `TextViews` one after another like the cards in the Google Now app. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other) and I tried to follow its instructions, but all animations are playing at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

This is the animation I want to play:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromDegrees="25"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

</set>
```

This is the layout I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.ReadUserProfile$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <com.yai.app.animation.support.NowLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e3e3e3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView"
            style="@style/nowCardStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaa"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView1"
            style="@style/nowCardStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bbb"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView2"
            style="@style/nowCardStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ccc"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView3"
            style="@style/nowCardStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ddd"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView4"
            style="@style/nowCardStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="eee"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    </com.yai.app.animation.support.NowLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try looping through the `Views` and start the `Animation` with `postDelayed()` like this:

```
View[] views = new View[] { ... };

// 100ms delay between Animations
long delayBetweenAnimations = 100; 

for(int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
    final View view = views[i];

    // We calculate the delay for this Animation, each animation starts 100ms 
    // after the previous one
    long delay = i * delayBetweenAnimations;

    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.your_animation);    
            view.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the animationListener

and do somthing like this for every textView

```
  @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        another_text.startAnimation(animation1);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is not a standard way, but it works for me better than other answers.
I make an anim resource file for each view I want to animate after each other and gave each next animation more duration time.
for example if we have three textviews which we want to animate right to left after each other , we make two anim files .xml like this:

anim1.xml :

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="500"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="0"
android:duration="1000">

</translate>
```

anim2.xml :

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="1000"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="0"
android:duration="1500">

</translate>
```

and than in my activity I set my textview like this:

```
new AnimationUtils();
Animation anim_one= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.anim.anim1);
Animation anim_two = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim2);
txt1.startAnimation(anim_one);
txt2.startAnimation(anim_two);
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate Views, we want the views to be invisible and become visible with the animation, right ?

This is how i accomplished that.

```
             int i = 0;
             long delayBetweenAnimations = 100L;

             while (viewsContainer.getChildAt(i) != null) {
                final View v = viewsContainer.getChildAt(i);
                v.setVisibility(View.Gone);                 //make the view invisible because the animation will take time to start
                i++; 
                long delay = i * delayBetweenAnimations;   //increase the delay time so each view's animation take longer time.

                    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() { 
                            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   //make the view visible now
                            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.lefttoright);
                            v.startAnimation(animation);
                        }
                    }, delay);
            }
```