# How to show and replace the values of an array in textview in Android Studio?

Tags: android, arrays

I'm a beginner in android developement and I want to build a small app that gives you the possibility to show the values of an `Array` into the `TextView` but I want it to show one value and then it disappears then the second value disappears and so on. This will happen after the `onClick()` method.

This is my Java Code :

```
  public void GetMyIdea(View view)  {
    String testatrix[]={"a","s","d", "f","g"};
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    for(int l=0; l<1; l++){
        tv.append(testatrix[l]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do some kind [of animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other) or just show them one at a time? You haven't really given enough specifics about what you want and what you are stuck on.

Comment: My app idea is to show the values of the array in the text view : I want that this algorithm execute like this :
-> click on the button
-> the show of the  first value 
-> the click on the button
-> the clean of the first value 
-> the show of the second value
-> click on the button
-> the clean of the second value.
-> the show of the third value

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
try this
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int l=0; l<1; l++){
        strBuilder.append(testatrix[l]);
    }
tv.setText(strBuilder.toString());

Comment: @comeback4you I try your code and he just show the first value of the string after the button click he did not pass to the next value

Answer (score 2):

```
String testatrix[]={"a","s","d", "f","g"};
int i=0;
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

public void showText(){

        tv.setText(testatrix[i]);
        i++;
        if(i>4){
           i=0;
        }                    
}
```

Call `showText` on click