# How to delay between two animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public void fade(View view)
    {
        ImageView link=findViewById(R.id.link);
        link.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(2000);
        link.animate().rotation(180f).setDuration(2000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView link=findViewById(R.id.link);
        link.setScaleX(.2f);
        link.setScaleY(.2f);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to expand the image and then rotate it but the image seems to rotate and expand at the same time. Any suggestions on how I can delay between the two animations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Animation one after other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple of options you can use to achieve this:

- Use [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet). It's a special class designer to coordinate animations. The drawback is that it can't work with `ValuePropertyAnimator`s, so you have to manually animate your views.
- Use `withEndAction(Runnable)` when running your first view animation. In the runnable parameter, just start the second animation.
- Use `setListener(AnimatorListener)` when running your first animation. Override `onAnimationEnd()` and start your second animation.