# android animation without delay

Tags: android, android-animation

I have anim file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="60000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

and I want animation to start immediately. But is starts after 2-3 sec delay. What can be the reason?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other

Comment: Please share a gif image as well

Answer (score 0):

Its working properly in my code. So there are no error in XML. Please check your Java. My Java code is:

```
   void startAnim() {
        view.clearAnimation();
        Animation anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ImageView logo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    logo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);

    Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.anim);
    logo.startAnimation(myanim);


}
```