# how to schedule animation on card views in android studio?

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to show card-views one after other via animations in android studio.

c1 and c2 are cardviews and there are other as well I want to show them via fadein animation one after another.

```
    final Animation animation1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein); 


    c1.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            c2.startAnimation(animation1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other)

Comment: Idts I will have to create 20 animations and 20 animationListeners to apply different annimation on 20 cardviews. The answer you identified won't work efficiently in my case.

Comment: Something like this? https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's inefficient but worked for me ...

```
    final Animation animation1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation3=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation4=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation5=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation6=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation7=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation8=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation9=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation10=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation11=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation12=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation13=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation14=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation15=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation16=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation17=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation18=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation19=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);
    final Animation animation20=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.fadein1);

    c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    c1.startAnimation(animation1);
    animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c2.startAnimation(animation2);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });


    animation2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c3.startAnimation(animation3);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });


    animation3.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c4.startAnimation(animation4);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });


    animation4.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c5.startAnimation(animation5);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation5.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c6.startAnimation(animation6);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation6.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c7.startAnimation(animation7);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation7.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            c8.startAnimation(animation8);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation8.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c9.startAnimation(animation9);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation9.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c10.startAnimation(animation10);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });



    animation10.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c11.startAnimation(animation11);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation11.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c12.startAnimation(animation12);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation12.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c13.startAnimation(animation13);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation13.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c14.startAnimation(animation14);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation14.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c15.startAnimation(animation15);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation15.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c16.startAnimation(animation16);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation16.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c17.startAnimation(animation17);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation17.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            c19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c18.startAnimation(animation18);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation18.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            c20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            c19.startAnimation(animation19);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    animation19.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            c20.startAnimation(animation20);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

fadein1.xml code in res/anim.

```
<alpha
    android:duration="7000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```